# Unix Shell SFTP Auto Download File

Tags: shell, unix, sftp

I am new in Unix Script, below is my script, I get this error when execute this file:
/root/bin/autodownload.sh: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
while [ 1 ]  
do
        sftp -o IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/ixxx akzo_extmy@10.x.x.x << EOF    
        cd outbound
        lcd /home/xxx/    
        get Abc*
        bye
        EOF
        sleep 60
done
```

Comment: put the `EOF` at the start of the line - it's not interpreted as the end of the here document if it's not at the start of the line.

Comment: OR use `<<-EOF` which allows/requires tabs for the indentation. The closing `EOF` must be tab indented (as many as you want). the block inside  can be leading tabs and spaces. I often use `\t\t\t\s\s\s\s` (not those literal values, just the regular <tab> and <space> keys)  to have a 4 space 2ndary indent (say for comments or other reasons). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter `<<-EOM` *requires* tabs for the 'stripping'/'ignoring' behaviour, which makes it really finicky and all too easy to mess up

Comment: @Petesh ; yep,  *requires* is the correct verb. Thanks for the correction. Personally, I prefer to have my `EOM` indented so I've learned to watch my tabs ;-) Each to his own. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

You need to delete spaces before EOF.  EOF should be at the left margin:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]  
do
        sftp mdogru@localhost << EOF 
        cd outbound
        lcd /home/mdogru/    
        get Abc*
        bye
EOF
        sleep 60

done
```